# How to start Windows service of client system from server system?

Tags: windows, service

I have developed a windows service using C#.net. The purpose of this service is block an application. When ever serrvice starts the application will be blocked. Can I operate this service from server to start or stop in client system?

Comment: it depends on how the "block" is realized...

Answer (score 1):

Try 'sc' command from the command prompt. As servers IP and services name use your own.

Starting service:

```
sc \\192.168.1.100 start MySQL
```

Stopping service:

```
sc \\192.168.1.100 start MySQL
```

More information [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192).